# MongoDB- how find same value in one field

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get all documents that the name field with the same title.

```
{
"_id": "5fe41c033ecd5c341457dec33",
"title": "My Post",
"user": "Alex",
"createdAt": "1998-11-21T11:12:34:15Z",  
}
```

And my expected output is not aggregated or grouped it by title, just find and output all documents with same title (not must is "My Post").
I only find answer is related two or more fileds with same value.

Comment: You can use the https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-equality

Comment: @prasad_ thank you, but the title do not must is "My Post", maybe is "My Edit" and others, so cannot use specific value to filter it. And you provide link I think use specific value to do find.

Comment: Try `$ne` operator.

Answer (score 1):

use $group

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
      _id: "$title",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      data : {
        $push : "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

output :

```
[
{
"_id": "My Post",
count : 1
data : [
  {
     "title": "My Post",
     "user": "Alex",
     "createdAt": "1998-11-21T11:12:34:15Z",  
  }
]
}
]
```

if you wanna find which title has more than 2, add $match

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group : {
      _id: "$title",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      data : {
        $push : "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
  {
    $match : {count : {$gt : 1}} 
  }
])
```

playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/TT0cbY3xaPK

Comment: wow, this so cool, that work perfectly and very thank for your help